# Are SPD-SL cleats compatible with old LOOK red delta pedals?

Tags: compatibility, cleat, pedals-clipless

I'm wanting to put LOOK Delta pedals off my old bike onto a bike that doesn't have clip-ins. This is going to be a spare/trainer bike. But my regular cleats for my regular 5000 miles (8000 km) a year road bike are SPD-SL Will they work with the old delta pedals?

I hate to buy new pedals just for the spare bike. When shopping for pedals I read a comment that said he had done just that -- used his spd's on the delta pedals.  I tried it out and they definitely clip in and I got them adjusted.  But this was on the old trainer and not out on the road.  I just don't want to have a problem when I'm out on the road 20 miles from home or having to make a sudden stop.

Comment: I'd say keep trying on the trainer, and if they clip and unclip consistently and you're comfortable, then and only then take them out on the road.

Comment: Use the correct cleats for the pedals and vice-versa, as intended by the manufacturer, to avoid any problems. Using Shimano cleats on Delta pedals is likely to damage the cleats and you may run into problems with your road-bike. The worst case being failure to unclip.